# what is tha actuall use of shut down hook in java

Tags: java, multithreading, shutdown-hook

I m learning java, 
i m unable to understand the actual use of shutdown hook in java means where it actually use ?

```
class MyThread extends Thread{  
    public void run(){  
        System.out.println("shut down hook task completed..");  
    }  
}  

public class Shutdown {  
public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {  

Runtime r=Runtime.getRuntime();  
r.addShutdownHook(new MyThread());  

System.out.println("Now main sleeping... press ctrl+c to exit");  
try{Thread.sleep(3000);}catch (Exception e) {}  
}  
}
```

i got this when i search for it could anyone help me to understand it

Comment: What part of the documentation don't you understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you have some resource that must be closed (or released) on shutdown. Typical examples include connections to external databases (perhaps within a *connection pool*), or displaying a message to the user (as in your post), or a file handle, or any and all of the above.

Comment: But there is no guarantee that the shutdown hook will execute, so it's best not to depend on it.

Comment: Aren't finalizers for that?

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of a shutdown hook is to perform actions while your application is shutting down.

For example, it was necessary for the application to save a state file or remove a lock file as part of the shutdown ... no matter *how* or *why* the shutdown was happening<sup>†</sup>.

---

How does this relate to shutdown of the Operating System?

Well, it depends on *how* the operating system shuts down.  If the OS does an orderly shutdown, then you would expect it to send a "SIGTERM" or similar event to all of the running processes, including the JVM running your application.  That would normally trigger a JVM shutdown, and the application-defined shutdown hooks would run.

On the other hand, if the OS did an emergency shutdown, or if you did a hard reboot by cycling the power, then you would not expect the hooks to run.

But this is all OS specific, and outside of Java's control.

---

<sup>† - But a shutdown hook is not *guaranteed* to always run.  1) One of the shutdown hooks might lock up, stopping others from running.  2) There are ways to kill a JVM process that will prevent shutdown hooks from running. 3) The JVM could hard crash.  4) The power to the CPU could go off ....</sup>

Comment: hey can you plz tell me ,is it the  shut down like our normal system shutdown

Comment: A JVM shutdown is another way of saying "when your application ends".  It could finish normally, or it could "crash" by throwing an exception that isn't caught.  (It is not clear what you mean by "our normal system shutdown".  If you mean shutdown of the OS, then the behavior of the JVM will depend on how the OS decides to "kill" it.)

Comment: thnks Stephen and yes I m asking about the shutdown of the os